# JDBC postgres statement_timeout

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

Suppose I have:

```
untimedStatement = connection.createStatement() ;
timedStatement = connection.createStatement();
```

And then run

```
timedStatement.execute("SET statement_timeout TO " + timeout);
```

Will the SET statement_timeout command also affect untimedStatement?  I was hoping it would not but some of the behaviour I'm observing suggests that SET statement_timeout has a "universal" effect (at least for the life of the program)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as long as they are executed on the same connection.

You can use SET LOCAL statement_timeout to make it affect only the current transaction. [Details](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-set.html).